# How to find out if a row with a specific primary key exists in a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, clustered-index

1. I have created a table in SQL which is named `testTable` like this where I have defined the:
   `PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime)`

```
CREATE TABLE testTable
(
    [DateTime]    SMALLDATETIME  NOT NULL,
    [FeatureNbr]  SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [Value]       FLOAT (53)         NULL,
    [Bool]        BIT                NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UC_testTable UNIQUE (DateTime),
    CONSTRAINT PK_testTable PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime)
);
```

2. I have now inserted 4 rows to the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Value, Bool) VALUES('10/22/2010 22:47', 0, 0.7556864869907925, 0);
INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Value, Bool) VALUES('10/22/2010 22:40', 5, 0.7556864869907925, 0);
INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Value, Bool) VALUES('10/22/2010 21:48', 0, 0.7556864869907925, 0);
INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Value, Bool) VALUES('10/22/2010 18:48', 20, 0.7556864869907925, 0);
```

3. Now assume that this table has 100 million rows or more. What is the fastest way to return if the above rows EXIST by looking at the primary key `FeatureNbr, DateTime`
   We are then looking for exactly the rows which has those primary keys:

- `0, '10/22/2010 22:47'`
- `5, '10/22/2010 22:40'`
- `0, '10/22/2010 21:48'`
- `20, '10/22/2010 18:48'`

I will for example look for 5000 rows like this. Do I need to in some kind of loop look for each row one by one(**perheps an exact search is extremely fast in this case?** or how do I return a result for all lines or for each search one by one?).
I will know the `FeatureNbr` which always are all integers between 0-5000. So we have only 1 of each here which makes it 5000 rows. However, - `DateTime` will be different for each `FeatureNbr.

I have found this line but I don't know how to apply this , -or if this is the correct thing to use?

```
If IndexProperty(Object_Id('testTable'), 'MyIndex', 'IndexID') Is Null
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried to look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

I describes how to `INNER JOIN`. It seems that I got the correct result using the below code.

- Assuming that `testTable` is the one with 100 Million Rows
- Assuming that `testTable2` is the one with 5000 Rows

I could find the exact matches for `FeatureNbr` and `DateTime` as a result.

Please tell if I do miss anything there or if I am thinking wrong so I can edit the post.

```
SELECT testTable.DateTime, testTable.FeatureNbr
FROM testTable
INNER JOIN testTable2 ON testTable.FeatureNbr=testTable2.FeatureNbr AND 
                         testTable.DateTime=testTable2.DateTime;
```